# Amazon EC2 spot instance requests seem to be throttled

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can't get more than 2 spot instances into to be fulfilled at any given time.

- Requests are for m3.large Windows instances.
- Request bids are above the current price for all zones in us-east-1
- Account Spot Request limitation is currently 40.
- Account limit for m3.large instances is 20.

If I manually request 3 I receive a status of capacity-oversubscribed for the third, always. If I cancel one of the two that are fulfilled, the third is fulfilled.

If I request 3 through the API, 2 are fulfilled and I get a status of az-group-constraint. If I cancel one of the successful requests, the third is fulfilled.

This seems like I'm hitting some kind of limitation that I'm not aware of or some kind of throttling.

This is request array I'm sending over:

```
Array
(
    [DryRun] => false
    [SpotPrice] => 0.13
    [InstanceCount] => 1
    [Type] => one-time
    [ValidUntil] => 1418087849 // about an hour from the original request
    [LaunchGroup] => d4768b0ba115414a70d2fd8ffe3e6d67 // unique to each request
    [AvailabilityZoneGroup] => us-east-1
    [LaunchSpecification] => Array
        (
            [InstanceType] => m3.large
            [ImageId] => ami-34222d5c
            [KeyName] => thu
            [Monitoring] => Array
                (
                    [Enabled] => false
                )
            [SecurityGroupIds] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sg-31273f54
                )
        )
```

Comment: By default, there is also a limit of the total number of instances that account can run (regardless of instance type). It is set to 20. Are you running any other instances at the same time? Check the "Limits" tab in your EC2 Management Console to view your limits.

Comment: Running On-Demand EC2 Instances is 40. Spot Instance Request Limits are 40. Reserved Instance limits are 40.

Comment: Try selecting a different Availability Zone, see if it helps. The default is "No preference".